# Magento 2 - get wrong locale which I set in system config?

Tags: magento2, locale

In Magento 2, I get wrong locale which I set in system config?

The first, I go to admin->set config locale is Japanese.
[image]

And then, I go to class "\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone"

```
....
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getDateFormat($type = \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT)
    {
        var_dump($this->_localeResolver->getLocale());
        return (new \IntlDateFormatter(
            $this->_localeResolver->getLocale(),
            $type,
            \IntlDateFormatter::NONE
        ))->getPattern();
    }
.......
```

And then I got the result: "en_US".
Did you see the same issue in your system?
If you have solution, may you help me please?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `getDateFormat()` ?

Comment: the first, I would like to get "ja_JP" locale, and then I get the date format of Japanese( "yyyy/MM/dd").

Answer (score 0):

I see only one reason why this happens - incorrect locale was set in the configuration. Please check your configuration ("store view" scope):

[image]

In a debug I see that magento works fine.

**Configuration** (`ja_JP`):

[image: config]

**Result** (`ja_JP` as set):

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue, because my admin account set locale is "US".
My solution here: set interface locale is Japanese.

[image]